# Can someone tell me why one of these JavaScript code works and one doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want the animation to stop when the number of clicks reach certain number.
Why the first snippet works, and the second one doesn't.
The only difference is where clearInterval is called.
This one works --- stops the animation.

```
var intervalId = setInterval(moveHeading, intervalLength);
var intervalLength = 120;
var clicks = 0; 
$("#heading").click(function () { 
    clearInterval(intervalId);  
    clicks++; 
    intervalLength /= 2;
    if (clicks >= 3) { 
      $("#heading").text("You Win!");
    } else {
      $("#heading").text(clicks);
      intervalId = setInterval(moveHeading, intervalLength);
    }
});
```

However this one one won't work --- doesn't stop animation.

```
var intervalId = setInterval(moveHeading, intervalLength);
var intervalLength = 120;
var clicks = 0; 
$("#heading").click(function () {  
    clicks++; 
    intervalLength /= 2;
    if (clicks > 3) {
      clearInterval(intervalId); 
      $("#heading").text("You Win!");
    } else {
      $("#heading").text(clicks);
      intervalId = setInterval(moveHeading, intervalLength);
    }
});
```

Comment: In your second sample, you're stacking `setInterval` multiple times. Indeed, you stopped it with `clearInterval` when `clicks > 3`, but you actually already had 3 other intervals running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the first one, you `clearInterval`, then overwrite `intervalId` when you call `setInterval`, so you will never have a `setInterval` that is still running, where you no longer know the `intervalId`.

On the second one, if `clicks <= 3`, then you will overwrite `intervalId`, but you never cleared the running `setInterval`, so it will continue to run, and you will never be able to `clearInterval` on it since you don't know it's id (you will just be able to clear the interval for whatever new interval you created).

Comment: Thanks I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval()` method will execute the function once every 1 second, just like a digital watch.
we have to use `clearInterval()` to stop the time.
It clears a timer set with the `setInterval()` method.
You must have to use it, in order to stop your animations.